# Django with Stripe webhooks not working with Stripe CLI, but Postman works localhost

Tags: django, stripe-payments

I'm trying to implement webhooks in Django with Stripe, but I'm facing an issue where the webhook is not getting triggered after a successful purchase using the Stripe CLI. However, the webhook works perfectly fine when tested using Postman.

I've tried multiple libraries and packages, including downloading repositories for webhooks integrated with Django and Stripe, but the problem still persists. I've double-checked all the URLs and made sure that every step has been taken correctly. I'm not including any code here as I've tried many different approaches and downloaded git repos just to test the webhooks, but the problem remains the same.

I'm using Windows 11 with VSCode, Stripe CLI, Django Rest Framework, and I've even tried turning off the firewalls, but to no avail. On the other hand, when I tested the Stripe CLI with a NodeJS app, the webhook fired as it should.

Can anyone help me troubleshoot this issue and make the webhook work with Django and Stripe CLI?

Answer (score 0):

The solution to the problem was to install the Stripe VSCode extension. This made the webhook work with Django and Stripe CLI.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).